# how to properly pytest a function with the same code used to seed a module scope fixture

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I have a fixture I created that pulls data from a database and puts it into a DataFrame so all subsequent tests can run on the same query output.  The same code is staged in a function that kicks of my data processing pipeline (which I am building all these tests around).  I am not sure I want to mock the db query result because I want to test the returned column names from the query and record uniqueness among other things.

Where I am confused is how to properly test the function I have in my code that is doing the same thing as the `output_data` fixture.  Is it proper to duplicate the code in my app for the fixture?

```py
# df_service.py
from project.settings import MSSQL_DB_CON_STR as con

def df_from_sql(start_date, months):     
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM dbo.awesome_table_value_function('{start_date}', {months})"    
    return pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=con)
```

Here is the fixture I started with before I recognized I am creating a fixture for functionality I actually want to test and use as a fixture.

```py
# test_df_service.py

import pytest
import pandas as pd

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def output_data():
    from project.settings import MSSQL_DB_CON_STR as con

    start_date = "11/1/2019"
    months = 4
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM dbo.awesome_table_value_function('{start_date}', {months})"    
    return pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=con)   

    return pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=con)

def test_columns(output_data):
    expected_columns = ['entity','attribute','value','effective_date']
    df = output_data
    for col in df.columns:
        assert col in expected_columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one way you could go about this is the following:

Since the `df_from_sql()` function is within the domain of your application, it should be also a function you actually want to test. So, I would write a pytest test for the function, asserting things like `Does it return X number of columns` or `Is the number of rows > 0`, etc (if you cannot guarantee to return the same data every time).

I see why you would want to use the function to create a fixture, however that introduces the following risks:

- The function to get the data for some reason doesn't work. Then all your tests might fail because your `ouput data` is not what they expected.
- The data in the database might change, so you would get different results to what you expected.

In theory, fixtures are supposed to be as fixed in space and time as possible, so what I would recommend is to actually save the data that you need as the `output_data` fixture in some file, or maybe in a mock table in your database, ensuring it will never change.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly with my sumary?

1) Test the `df_from_sql` function by asserting things like the columns it is returning

2) In separate tests that operate on the `df_from_sql` result use static data in a fixture.

Comment: That is what I meant,yes